# Return select objects and only desired subvalues from a list of lists using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I couldn't find a solution to this seemingly straightforward LINQ problem.

I'm trying to return a list of objects where each object has a certain value in a property sublist. I need to return the object and only return those sublist values

Ex:

My classes simplified:

```
public class Fruit()
{
   public List<KeyValuePairs> items {get;set;)
}
```

```
public class KeyValuePair()
{
   public string Key {get;set;}
   public string Value {get;set;}
}
```

My list of Fruits:

```
fruitList = new List<Fruit>(){Fruit1, Fruit2, Fruit3, Fruit4}


Fruit1.items = {name: apple, color: red}
Fruit2.items = {name: apple, color: green}
Fruit3.items = {name: apple, date: 2020}
Fruit4.items = {name: grape, color: green}
```

Return only the fruits with "color" in the sublist, and only return the "color" key/value from its sublist. So the result would look something like:

```
Fruit1.items = {color: red}
Fruit2.items = {color: green}
Fruit4.items = {color: green}
```

I appreciate the help!

Comment: You need to show actual C# types and not vague pseudo-types to get an answer. It doesn't seem like a good idea to return the original objects and modify the original objects `items` member to have different data, but if that is what you really want, then LINQ alone is for querying, not for modifying objects.

Comment: I assume your `class KeyValuePair` is a typo and you meant `KeyValuePairs`.

Comment: `Fruit1.items = {name: apple, color: red}` makes no sense at all; it's not legal c# syntax. Please update the code with an actual example. Do you mean `Fruit1.items = new List<KeyValuePair> { new KeyValuePair { Key = "apple", Value = "red"}}`? But if so, where does "color" come into play? This question is unanswerable as it stands.

Comment: Sure I'll get right on that, but can you first help me out with all these red squiggly lines in my code?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the `Key` in your `Items` is unique. You don't have two `KeyValuePairs` with the `Key` "Color".

The following, as given by others will work:

```
var result = from fruit in fruitList
    where fruit.items.Any(i => i.Key == "color")
    select new {Color = fruit.items.First(i => i.Key == "color").Value};
```

However, for this you will scan the sequence of `Items` more than once: once to see if there is at least one `Key` with value "color", throw away the result, and start again at the first `Item` to find the first `Item` with `Key` "color".

Of course this can be done more efficient: From every `Fruit`, get its data and its first `Item` with `Key` equal to "color" or default, then throw away every `Fruit` that doesn't have any such first `Item`.

In your (probably simplified) example a Fruit has only Items. In that case it can be done even simpler. But let's first assume that a Fruit has several other properties that I want:

```
string keyToSelect = "color";
var result = fruits.Select(fruit => new
{
    SelectedItem = fruit.Items
        .Where(item => item.Key == keyToSelect)
        .FirstOrDefault(),

    // Select other Fruit properties that you plan to use,
    // or skip this if a Fruit has no other properties
    Name = fruit.Name,
    ...
})

// Keep only those Fruits that have a FirstItemWithKeyToSelect:
.Where(fruit => fruit.SelectedItem!= null);
```

This takes your first Fruit, and starts enumerating the Items until it finds the first one with Key == "color". It remembers this Item, ans skips the rest of the Items. Then it continues with the Items of the second Fruit, etc Until it has enumerated all Fruits.

So Items are scanned at utmost once. After you've found a suitable Item of a certain Fruit, the rest of the Items of the Fruit are not scanned.

Comment: Thanks Harald, I think one of my hiccups was that I didn't realize that you could produce "new" objects from within the LINQ query, or that by creating new objects the query efficiency would be compromised in comparison to just "filtering" the original object list. I was under the impression that I could just drop data from each  object "items" property and returning the original object. What you posted is much clearer and gets the job done. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Using Linq seems like the best idea.

```
var result = from fruit in fruitList
             where fruit.items.Any(i => i.Key == "color")
             select new {Color = fruit.items.First(i => i.Key == "color").Value};
```

This returns anonymous types.

Answer (score 0):

Solution which does not preserve the actual instance of the object:

```
fruitList.Where(f => f.items.Any(i => i.Key == "color")).Select(f => new Fruit { items = f.items.Where(i => i.Key == "color").ToList() });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is done using Linq Select statiment where you pass lambda function that return what you want. This is very useful in can you wanna pass specific implementation on the object before returning it. It's something like the following:

```
fruitList.Where(x => x.Value == "red").Select(s =>
{
  return s.Value;
});
```

**Edit**

```
.Select(s =>
                {
                    return s.items.Where(itm=>itm.Value.StartsWith("y"))
                    .Select(itm => { return itm.Value; }).ToList<string>();
    
                });
```

Comment: `Fruit` does not have a property called `Value`. It encapsulates a list of Key/Values

Comment: something like that might help:
.Select(s =>
                {
                    return s.items.Where(itm=>itm.Value.StartsWith("y"))
                    .Select(itm => { return itm.Value; }).ToList<string>();
    
                });
you can ignore ToList<String>() or convert it to different type

Answer (score -1):

LINQ is good for filtering and querying, but not for modifying data. Since you want to change the original objects to filter the `items` member, you need to process each after finding them.

1. First, use LINQ to get a list of the proper `Fruit` objects:

   ```
   var ans = fruitList.Where(f => f.items.Any(kv => kv.Key == "color")).ToList();
   ```
2. Modify each `Fruit` to only have the desired `items` members:

   ```
   foreach (var fruit in ans)
       fruit.items = fruit.items.Where(kv => kv.Key == "color").ToList();
   // ans is original Fruit objects now with filtered items members
   ```